# Manipulating message card object - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send a script from Google spreadsheet to Google spaces and here is the code that works perfectly.

However upon sending it, it truncates the entire table to single row and pastes in a single line.

I am not sure of how to manipulate or modify so that it appears as a proper table or at least a screenshot.

Appreciate the help.

Here is the code

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email");
  var dataGrid = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 3, 3).getValues();

  var WebWhooklink = "Sample_URL"
  var message = { text: dataGrid.toString() }; // <- here
  var payload = JSON.stringify(message);
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(WebWhooklink, options).getContentText();
}
```

Attached is the spreadsheet which needs to be sent in a table or an image (Range = A2:D16)[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gNGbwlCJW7Z0fjcJzMHrLsVH9c_v_dGTwYsF8Std9MA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email");
  var dataGrid = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 3, 3).getDisplayValues();

  var WebWhooklink = "Sample_URL"
  var message = { text: dataGrid }; 
  var payload = JSON.stringify(message);
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(WebWhooklink, options).getContentText();
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error. Exception: 

Request failed for https://chat.googleapis.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"text\" at 'message': Proto field is not repeating, ca... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

myFunction @ ms_new.gs:14

Comment: is it me or do I think the documentation just changed? https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks. This is just above my head, apologies!